# is there any plugin for complicated searching with mongoid (like meta_search for ActiveRecord)?

Tags: ruby, mongoid, meta-search

I tried meta_search, but after adding "include MetaSearch::Searches::ActiveRecord" into my model, it raised an error as "undefined method `joins_values'" when run "MyModel.search(params[:search])"

I think I dont need full text, so I think following gems are not suitable for my project now::
mongoid_fulltext
mongoid-sphinx
sunspot_mongoid
mongoid_search

I tried a old gem named scoped-search
I can make it work for example:

```
get :search do
  @search        = Notification.scoped_search(params[:search]
  search_scope   = @search.scoped
  defaul_scope   = current_user.notifications
  result_scope   = search_scope.merge defaul_scope
  @notifications = result_scope

  render 'notifications/search'
end
```

but it will be allow to call any scopes in my model.

Is there any "best practice" for doing this job ?

Comment: Why you want limit the scope usage on your search ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want limit the scope you want use on your scoped_search you can filter your params[:search] like :

```
def limit_scope_search
  params[:search].select{|k,v| [:my_scope, :other_scope_authorized].include?(k) }
end
```

Comment: I'm really miss the "search_methods" by meta_search gem, it's using for define a white list for which scopes can be used in the search form.
Maybe it's not a bad idea to filter the scarchable scopes in controller, I think it's OK for me.
But the point of my question is "is there any plugin for complicated searching with mongoid (like meta_search for ActiveRecord)?"